# How do I solve the error of disk space while configuring minikube

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I am working on starting minikube locally with the command `minikube start` and the system responds with the error shown in the picture. I have emptied almost all of my `/var` files in my local machine and I still encounter errors.

I have consumed some links online but still to no avail. Please help with how this can be sorted.

Thanks.

[image: screenshot of minikube error]

Comment: "I have emptied almost all of my /var files in my local machine..." And how much space was left when you were done? Maybe you just need to resize your filesystems, or locate Docker storage somewhere else.

Comment: How do I locate Docker storage in another location?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the output from the `df -h /var` command ?

Comment: `
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       687G  646G  5.8G 100% /`
@matt_j The response of `df -h /var` is shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube has a default disk size and a minimum disk size that you might be able to leverage in order to save space, you can have a look [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) for this information

```
2 CPUs or more
2GB of free memory
20GB of free disk space
```

At the same time you can change the disk that docker is going to use for storing data with something like:

```
minikube start --disk-size=20g --docker-opt="--data-root /mnt/sdX"
```

But you need another disk or partition with free space for that to work, from your updated info, /dev/sdb2 is full so you need another partition with free space on /dev/sdb or a new disk to be attached to the server, let's say /dev/sdc or something like that with free space.
Or increase the size of your /var FS

Another thing that you can do is reconfigure docker in order for it to avoid using the default /var/lib/docker path for data and configure it to another fs with more space available, you might like to have a look at the following [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) for more details:

Comment: For the first comment, I have over 40GB of free disk space, then for the second comment, the command is still giving the same error as the question.

Comment: can you share the output from df -hP from your system? and lsblk?

Comment: check out the answer I added to see the response of the command

Comment: there looks like that you don't have much space left, right? 5.8G on / and /var does not have its own fs, another thing that you might be running into when seeing no space on the device but seeing free space with df -h is that might not be more inodes free, you can see such thing with df -i, anyway I'll update my answer

Comment: I saw your updated response but how do I create the /dev/sdc?

Comment: you need to attack a new disk, each /dev/sdX is a disk

Comment: Is there a way I could change the directory ? (i.e instead of the docker and minikube referencing /var, I make it reference another partition)

Comment: You need to understand that directory does not equal to partition, you have disks and then you create partitions and then you mount those partitions on paths that might be directories, anyway from what you posted I think you don't have any other partitions on your disk available right? and in case of having one you might be able to change that as I posted with the docker-ops argument